# User validation with HashMap on Servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets, hashmap, user-input

I have to create a small application where a user enters his/her username and password in an html form and then it is processed in a servlet which has a HashMap of users and passwords. The HashMap should be initialized with some usernames and passwords in the init method of the servlet. I have to check the user input with the HashMap entries and this is where I am stuck. I do not know how to compare the HashMap entries with the username and password entered by the user.
The code I have so far is as below:

```
    public class User {

    String username;
    String password;


    public User (String user, String pass){
        this.username = user;
        this.password = pass;

    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/AthorizationServlet")
public class AthorizationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public AthorizationServlet() {
        super();

    }


    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

        super.init(config);

        HashMap<Integer, User> uc = new HashMap <Integer, User>(); {
            uc.put(1, new User("user1", "pass1"));
            uc.put(2, new User ("user2", "pass2"));
            uc.put(3, new User ("user3", "pass3"));
            uc.put(4, new User ("user4", "pass4"));
        }
        Iterator<Entry<Integer, User>> it = uc.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            //some code to validate user input against HashMap entries
        }
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        String pass = request.getParameter("password"); 


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to say that the reason you are stuck is that a HashMap that maps User-name strings to passwords would require a `HashMap<String, String> uc`, but you have created a `HashMap<Integer, User> uc`, and that sort of eliminates the value of using the HashMap!  If you are planning to utilize the "optimization" that a java.util.HashMap provides - meaning that String's are "hashed" for quick & easy lookup in the data-structure, you would save the HashMap as follows:

```
HashMap<Integer, User> uc = new HashMap <Integer, User>(); {
    uc.put("user1", "pass1");
    uc.put("user2", "pass2");
    uc.put("user3", "pass3");
    uc.put("user4", "pass4");
}
```

In this fashion, you could lookup user-name & password combinations as follows:

```
public boolean checkPassword(String enteredUserName, String enteredPassword)
{
    String userPassword = uc.get(enteredUserName);
    return enteredPassword.equals(userPassword);
}
```

If you absolutely must use the "User" data structure in your HashMap, another alternative would be to:

```
    HashMap<Integer, User> uc = new HashMap <Integer, User>(); {
        uc.put("user1", new User("user1", "pass1"));
        uc.put("user2", new User ("user2", "pass2"));
        uc.put("user3", new User ("user3", "pass3"));
        uc.put("user4", new User ("user4", "pass4"));
    }
```

at which point getting a password could look like this:

```
public boolean checkPassword(String enteredUserName, String enteredPassword)
{
    String userPassword = uc.get(enteredUserName).getPassword();
    return enteredPassword.equals(userPassword);
}
```

I am not sure what the "Integer" (a User ID?) that you have used to initiate the `HashMap<Integer, User>` - ***HOWEVER*** - the most important thing to realize is that the purpose of a HashMap is that "lookup" in a table is much faster because a "Hash" function is performed on the lookup value.

> If you do not plan to look things up using the "User ID Integer", then
>   storing that as the key to a HashMap doesn't serve much purpose at
>   all.

Your iterator would have to iterate through the entire table to find the user:

```
public boolean checkPassword(String enteredUserName, String enteredPassord)
{
        Iterator<Entry<Integer, User>> it = uc.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            //some code to validate user input against HashMap entries
            User u = it.next().getValue();
            if (u.getUserName().equals(enteredUserName())
                return u.getPassword().equals(enteredPassword);
        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Firstly, I thought of using a user ID to compare the passwords and usernames that is why I added an integer in the HashMap but your response made me understand how it could be implemented better.